# Fetching entries for images uploaded using carrierwave + S3 takes long

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, amazon-s3, carrierwave

In my Rails app, when I render a list of several image urls (each image has 4 versions), it takes several seconds (as in 10's of seconds for 30 images x 4 versions). Using mini-profiler, I found for each image version Carrierwave is making a `HEAD NET::HTTP` request to S3 where the image versions are stored (120 requests x 0.1s = 12 secs).

This is too long and not scalable for production. How can I improve this?

The database query is in milliseconds. The list generated is a list of image url, using `image_object.filename.url(:version_size)`, and image size, using `image_object.filename.versions[:version_size].size`.

Using Rails 5rc1, Carrierwave with AWS for S3 storage.

Comment: slight nitpick, 120 * 0.1ms = 12ms

Comment: oops... its 0.1s or 100ms :)

Comment: `image_object.filename.versions[:version_size].size` I assume refers to size in bytes (not pixels)? I know the S3 API a little too intimately but not your platform/framework.  This is probably the cause of the `HEAD` requests.  Do you not have this information stored in a database?  Polling S3 for it seems unnecessarily costly at scale, not to mention performance ... although for code running inside EC2, if the bucket is in the same region, it should be a much faster process than 100ms each.

Comment: Yes I found out later that's the cause. Yes it's file size in bytes, not pixels. I store the file size for the original uploaded image in my db, but the way carrier wave works, is it creates versions and from what I can tell, there are no db entries for the versions for me to store file size or image sizes. I'm thinking maybe I'll have to create a db table to manage image versions url and meta data or add columns to the existing table. I wonder how others are dealing with this?? It's Heroku to S3, not sure if 100ms is normal for that.